# App with Spring and Hibernate does not compile on TeamCity with Java8 and Scala 2.11.8

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, teamcity

after migration of my app to Scala 2.11.8 and Java8 and updating Spring and Hibernate to versions as Follow:

```
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.asm.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.asm.version>
    <spring.ws.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.data.version>1.10.2.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
     <hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <hibernate.jpa.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate.jpa.version>
```

Locally mvn clean install -U works completely fine. If I run the build on TeamCity I get error as follow:

```
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hibernate/jdbc/ReturningWork : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[17:03:33][Step 3/3] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project app-jpa: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed.
```

I try to compile it with java-8-openjdk-amd64/

Any ideas how to solve this?

Best

Answer (score 0):

in my case I upgraded my JRE to the latest version, because the compiling version wasn't same as running version.